# Issue with dev-tools style editing in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt.js application, and I often need to check styles in my browser's dev-tools, but when I do make a change to the styles in the dev-tools all the styles reset in the browser? Has anyone one else had the same issue? I can't seem to find anything anywhere else about this??

Comment: Sometimes I got the same issue. It's appear when I'm editing complex dom tree with scoped css. It's not happen with firefox devtools.

Comment: In my case, I was importing a file 2 times

Answer (score 15, accepted):

on `nuxt.config.js` file, disable the `sourceMaps` for scss files with the loader property

```js
export default {
  // ...
  build: {
    loaders: {
      scss: { sourceMap: false },
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

see in ~> [nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#loaders](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#loaders)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was close to give up in this issue :)

Comment: Source maps is an idea that made things so much more complicated than they needed to be...

Comment: In my case I am using Stylus, so I had to make it `stylus: { sourceMap: false }` Others might run into this depending on their CSS flavor

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Nuxt v3. Can you provide guidance on how? (my detailed question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474831/how-to-can-i-sync-changes-in-chrome-devtools-styles-pane-to-original-source-fo)